Bounds for torsion in Betti cohomology
Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{N}_{\mathbb{C}}$ be a smooth, projective variety of dimension $n$ and degree $D$. Is there an upper bound on the torsion in the Betti cohomology groups $H^{i}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ in terms of $D$ and $N$?
Edit: Replaced $n$ with $N$. More precisely I'm looking for an explicit bound of the form $\mathrm{exp}(D^{N})$.

This seems likely to be true once you fix all discrete invariants (the Hilbert polynomial), for then you are left with a finite type family of subvarieties. But using only the dimension and degree seems fishy to me, as this still leaves infinitely many components of the Hilbert scheme.

@a17 I assume you are the same person who emailed me a few days (things are busy). If you want an explicit bound, rather than just existence, you should add that to your question.

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn I think this is OK, by working with Chow varieties instead of Hilbert schemes.

@DonuArapura yes that's right. Have edited the question accordingly.
